# Non-pure submonoid of $\mathbb R_+$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I saw the definition of **pure submonoid** in a paper: A submonoid $\mathbb A$ of $\mathbb R_+$ (as an additive monoid) is said to be **pure** if for any $r_0,r_1,r_2\in \mathbb R_+$ such that $r_0,r_2\in\mathbb A$ and $r_0+r_1=r_2$, then $r_1\in\mathbb A$.

As examples, $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q_+$ are all pure submonoids. My question is that is there any example for non-pure submonoid of $\mathbb R_+$?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{R}^+ - (0,1)$. Plenty of ways to build elements $r_2$ as the sum of something greater than 1, and something less than 1. This set is also clearly closed under addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any (non-trivial, pure) submonoid and remove some initial segment containing at least two elements but which doesn't contain all the elements. Then reinsert $0$. This will always make a non-pure submonoid.

Comment: Thank you! This is enlightening.